# GNU linker: errors if pointer in header file is declared NULL and/or extern

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I am testing some patches (C language) for BOINC client (C++ language), and during compilation I got a GNU linker error about `GDBusProxy* proxy = NULL;` line in file `linux/user_idle_time_detection.h` (complete file hereunder). So I started doing some attempts to modify the affected line, but I got two different errors (case 1 and 2 hereunder), and I really cannot understand why the linker does not like:

- the extern statement
- the pointer initialized at NULL;

Thank you

**CASE 1**

```
extern GDBusProxy* proxy;
```

returns error

```
/usr/bin/ld: boinc_client-user_idle_time_detection.o: in function `create_proxy':
/builddir/build/BUILD/boinc-client_release-7.14-7.14.2/client/linux/user_idle_time_detection.c:5: undefined reference to `proxy'
/usr/bin/ld: boinc_client-user_idle_time_detection.o: in function `get_user_idle_time':
/builddir/build/BUILD/boinc-client_release-7.14-7.14.2/client/linux/user_idle_time_detection.c:21: undefined reference to `proxy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**CASE 2**

Both

```
extern GDBusProxy* proxy = NULL;
```

and

```
GDBusProxy* proxy = NULL;
```

return error

```
/usr/bin/ld: boinc_client-hostinfo_unix.o:/builddir/build/BUILD/boinc-client_release-7.14-7.14.2/client/linux/user_idle_time_detection.h:7: multiple definition of `proxy'; boinc_client-user_idle_time_detection.o:/builddir/build/BUILD/boinc-client_release-7.14-7.14.2/client/linux/user_idle_time_detection.h:7: first defined here
```

**CASE 3**

The following works good instead

```
GDBusProxy* proxy;
```

## **SOURCE FILES**

**[linux/user_idle_time_detection.h](https://github.com/Germano0/boinc/blob/user_idle_time_detection/client/linux/user_idle_time_detection.h)**

```
#ifndef USER_IDLE_TIME_DETECTION_H
#define USER_IDLE_TIME_DETECTION_H
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include "gnome/gnome_dbus_interface.h"

GDBusProxy* proxy = NULL;
GDBusProxy* create_proxy();
double get_user_idle_time();
#endif /* USER_IDLE_TIME_DETECTION_H */
```

**[linux/user_idle_time_detection.c](https://github.com/Germano0/boinc/blob/user_idle_time_detection/client/linux/user_idle_time_detection.c)**

```
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include "user_idle_time_detection.h"
GDBusProxy* create_proxy()
{
    proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_for_bus_sync (G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION,
                                           G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
                                           NULL,
                                           GNOME_DBUS_SERVICE,
                                           GNOME_DBUS_PATH_SETTINGS,
                                           GNOME_DBUS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS,
                                           NULL, NULL);
    return proxy;
}

double get_user_idle_time()
{
    guint64 user_idle_time;
    double user_idle_time_double;
    GError* error = NULL;
    GVariant* ret = NULL;
    proxy = create_proxy();

    ret = g_dbus_proxy_call_sync(proxy,
                                  GNOME_DBUS_METHOD_SETTINGS,
                                  NULL,
                                  G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE, -1,
                                  NULL, &error);
    if (!ret) {
        g_dbus_error_strip_remote_error (error);
        g_print ("GetIdletime failed: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free (error);
        return;
    }

    g_variant_get(ret, "(t)", &user_idle_time);
    user_idle_time_double = (double)user_idle_time;
    g_variant_unref (ret);
    return user_idle_time_double;
}
```

**[linux/gnome/gnome_dbus_interface.h](https://github.com/Germano0/boinc/blob/user_idle_time_detection/client/linux/gnome/gnome_dbus_interface.h)**

```
#ifndef GNOME_DBUS_INTERFACE_H
#define GNOME_DBUS_INTERFACE_H

#define GNOME_DBUS_SERVICE "org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor"
#define GNOME_DBUS_PATH_SETTINGS "/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core"
#define GNOME_DBUS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS "org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor"
#define GNOME_DBUS_METHOD_SETTINGS "GetIdletime"
#endif /* GNOME_DBUS_INTERFACE_H */
```

[**hostinfo_unix.cpp**](https://github.com/Germano0/boinc/blob/user_idle_time_detection/client/hostinfo_unix.cpp)

```
#include "linux/user_idle_time_detection.h"
CUT
bool HOST_INFO::users_idle(bool check_all_logins, double idle_time_to_run) {
    double user_idle_time;
    double user_pref_idle_time_in_ms;
    //user_idle_time = get_user_idle_time();
    user_pref_idle_time_in_ms = (idle_time_to_run * 60000);
CUT
```

**[Makefile.am](https://github.com/Germano0/boinc/blob/user_idle_time_detection/client/Makefile.am)**

```
## -*- mode: makefile; tab-width: 4 -*-
## $Id$

include $(top_srcdir)/Makefile.incl

if ENABLE_CLIENT_RELEASE
  AM_LDFLAGS += -static-libtool-libs
## for an entirely statically linked library, you may want to try
## -all-static instead.  There's a good chance it won't work properly,
## so we'll use the safer "-static-libtool-libs" by default.
else
if DYNAMIC_CLIENT
## if libtool starts to need flags for dynamic linking, add them here
else
  AM_LDFLAGS += -static
endif
endif ## ENABLE_CLIENT_RELEASE

LIBS += $(CLIENTLIBS)

if OS_DARWIN
   LIBS += -framework IOKit -framework Foundation -framework ScreenSaver -framework Cocoa -framework CoreServices
endif

bin_PROGRAMS = boinc_client boinccmd
if !OS_WIN32
bin_PROGRAMS += switcher
endif

boinccmd_SOURCES = boinc_cmd.cpp
boinccmd_DEPENDENCIES = $(LIBBOINC)
boinccmd_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS)
boinccmd_LDFLAGS = $(AM_LDFLAGS) -L$(top_srcdir)/lib
boinccmd_LDADD = $(LIBBOINC) $(BOINC_EXTRA_LIBS) $(PTHREAD_LIBS)

boinc_client_SOURCES = \
    acct_mgr.cpp \
    acct_setup.cpp \
    app.cpp \
    app_config.cpp \
    app_control.cpp \
    app_start.cpp \
    async_file.cpp \
    check_state.cpp \
    client_msgs.cpp \
    client_state.cpp \
    client_types.cpp \
    coproc_sched.cpp \
    cpu_sched.cpp \
    cs_account.cpp \
    cs_apps.cpp \
    cs_benchmark.cpp \
    cs_cmdline.cpp \
    cs_files.cpp \
    cs_notice.cpp \
    cs_platforms.cpp \
    cs_prefs.cpp \
    cs_proxy.cpp \
    cs_scheduler.cpp \
    cs_statefile.cpp \
    cs_trickle.cpp \
    current_version.cpp \
    dhrystone.cpp \
    dhrystone2.cpp \
    file_names.cpp \
    file_xfer.cpp \
    gpu_amd.cpp \
    gpu_detect.cpp \
    gpu_intel.cpp \
    gpu_nvidia.cpp \
    gpu_opencl.cpp \
    gui_http.cpp \
    gui_rpc_server.cpp \
    gui_rpc_server_ops.cpp \
    hostinfo_linux.cpp \
    hostinfo_network.cpp \
    http_curl.cpp \
    log_flags.cpp \
    mac_address.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    net_stats.cpp \
    pers_file_xfer.cpp \
    project.cpp \
    project_list.cpp \
    result.cpp \
    rr_sim.cpp \
    sandbox.cpp \
    scheduler_op.cpp \
    thread.cpp \
    time_stats.cpp \
    whetstone.cpp \
    work_fetch.cpp \
    linux/user_idle_time_detection.c

boinc_client_DEPENDENCIES = $(LIBBOINC)
boinc_client_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(GIO_CFLAGS) $(GLIB_CFLAGS)
boinc_client_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(SSL_CXXFLAGS)
boinc_client_LDFLAGS = $(AM_LDFLAGS) $(SSL_LDFLAGS) $(GIO_LIBS) $(GLIB_LIBS)  -L$(top_srcdir)/lib
if OS_WIN32
boinc_client_CXXFLAGS += -I$(top_srcdir)/coprocs/NVIDIA/include
boinc_client_SOURCES += hostinfo_win.cpp \
    hostinfo_wsl.cpp \
    sysmon_win.cpp \
    win/boinc_cli.rc \
    win/res/boinc.ico
else
if OS_DARWIN
boinc_client_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-flat_namespace,-undefined,dynamic_lookup
else
boinc_client_SOURCES += hostinfo_unix.cpp
endif
endif
boinc_client_LDADD = $(LIBBOINC) $(LIBBOINC_CRYPT) $(BOINC_EXTRA_LIBS) $(PTHREAD_LIBS)

boinc_clientdir = $(bindir)

if OS_ARM_LINUX
boinc_client_LDADD += libwhetneon.a libwhetvfp.a
noinst_LIBRARIES = libwhetneon.a libwhetvfp.a
libwhetneon_a_SOURCES = whetstone.cpp
libwhetneon_a_CXXFLAGS = $(boinc_client_CXXFLAGS) -DANDROID_NEON -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon

libwhetvfp_a_SOURCES = whetstone.cpp
libwhetvfp_a_CXXFLAGS = $(boinc_client_CXXFLAGS) -DANDROID_VFP -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp
endif

switcher_SOURCES = switcher.cpp
switcher_LDFLAGS = $(AM_LDFLAGS) -L../lib
switcher_LDADD = $(LIBBOINC)

## since we are using libtool we need some magic to get boinc and boinc_client
## to both be installed properly.  The next two rules do that...
all-local: boinc$(EXEEXT)

boinc$(EXEEXT): boinc_client$(EXEEXT)
    rm -f boinc$(EXEEXT) .libs/boinc$(EXEEXT)
    $(LN) boinc_client$(EXEEXT) boinc$(EXEEXT)
    if test -f .libs/boinc_client$(EXEEXT) ; then $(LN) .libs/boinc_client$(EXEEXT) .libs/boinc$(EXEEXT) ; fi

install-exec-hook:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(exec_prefix)/bin/boinc$(EXEEXT)
    $(LN) $(DESTDIR)$(exec_prefix)/bin/boinc_client$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(exec_prefix)/bin/boinc$(EXEEXT)

## these source files need to be specified because no rule uses them.

EXTRA_DIST = *.h \
    mac \
    translation \
    win
```

**[Makefile.curl.am](https://github.com/Germano0/boinc/blob/user_idle_time_detection/client/Makefile.curl.am)**

```
## -*- mode: make; tab-width: 4 -*-
## $Id$

include $(top_srcdir)/Makefile.incl

# (for a while we used "-static -static-libgcc" on linux, but this is obsolete
# now)
#STATIC_FLAGS=@STATIC_FLAGS@

client-bin: @CLIENT_BIN_FILENAME@

LIBS += @CLIENTLIBS@

bin_PROGRAMS = boinc_client

EXTRA_PROGRAMS = cpu_benchmark

boinc_client_SOURCES = \
    acct_mgr.cpp \
    acct_setup.cpp \
    app.cpp \
    app_control.cpp \
    app_graphics.cpp \
    app_start.cpp \
    check_state.cpp \
    client_msgs.cpp \
    client_state.cpp \
    client_types.cpp \
    cs_account.cpp \
    cs_apps.cpp \
    cs_benchmark.cpp \
    cs_cmdline.cpp \
    cs_data.cpp \
    cs_files.cpp \
    cs_prefs.cpp \
    cs_scheduler.cpp \
    cs_statefile.cpp \
    cs_trickle.cpp \
    dhrystone.cpp \
    dhrystone2.cpp \
    file_names.cpp \
    file_xfer.cpp \
    gui_http.cpp \
    gui_rpc_server.cpp \
    gui_rpc_server_ops.cpp \
    hostinfo_linux.cpp \
    hostinfo_network.cpp \
    hostinfo_unix.cpp \
    http_curl.cpp \
    log_flags.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    net_stats.cpp \
    net_xfer_curl.cpp \
    pers_file_xfer.cpp \
    scheduler_op.cpp \
    time_stats.cpp \
    whetstone.cpp \
    linux/user_idle_time_detection.c

boinc_client_DEPENDENCIES = $(LIBRSA)
boinc_client_CPPFLAGS = -D_USE_CURL -I../../curl-7.14.0/include -I $(srcdir)/win $(AM_CPPFLAGS) -O3
boinc_client_LDFLAGS = -static-libgcc
boinc_client_LDADD = -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -L../../curl-7.14.0/lib -lcurl -L../lib -lboinc $(RSA_LIBS) $(PTHREAD_LIBS)
#boinc_client_LDFLAGS = $(STATIC_FLAGS)

# the following don't do anything
cpu_benchmark_SOURCES = whetstone.cpp dhrystone.cpp
cpu_benchmark_CFLAGS = -O3 $(AM_CFLAGS)

all-local: client-bin

# make a hard link to the client name.
@CLIENT_BIN_FILENAME@: boinc_client
    rm -f $@
    @LN@ $? $@
    @STRIP@ $@

## these source files need to be specified because no rule uses them.

EXTRA_DIST = *.h \
    mac \
    translation \
    win

clean-local:
    rm -f @CLIENT_BIN_FILENAME@
```

**[configure.ac](https://github.com/Germano0/boinc/blob/user_idle_time_detection/configure.ac)**
Cannot insert it here due Stackoverflow characters limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting a warning:

```
// This is wrong...
extern GDBusProxy* proxy = NULL;
```

```
warning: ‘proxy’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 extern GDBusProxy* proxy = NULL;
                    ^~~~~
```

The `extern` storage class specifier basically means "this is defined somewhere else", but the `= NULL` is not really somewhere else.

Just like functions, with variables you should:

- Declare them in the header file (compiled many times):

  ```
  extern GDBusProxy *proxy;
  ```

  This is a **declaration** and you can have as many declarations of a single object as you like (as long as they are all compatible).
- Define them in the C file (compiled once):

  ```
  GDBusProxy *proxy = NULL;
  ```

  This is a **definition** and you can only have one definition in your entire project. So it cannot appear in a header file, unless that header file is only included by one C file.

This not the only way to do it. You can use the following declaration everywhere:

```
GDBusProxy *proxy;
```

This is a special case, it counts as a **definition** but you are allowed to have more than one in your program.

Note that `= NULL` is redundant. Global variables are zero-initialized by default.

Answer (score 1):

In the case 1 you missed to define the variable in a source file, so its definition is missing

In the other cases having

> ```
> GDBusProxy* proxy = NULL;
> ```

in a header file does not declare the variable but define it, so including the header file in several sources define it several times.

replace it by

```
 extern GDBusProxy* proxy;
```

and define it in one of the source files